# Triggering Event when Leaving Liveview

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On a development phoenix server, in a liveview, I try to trigger an event when somebody leaves the liveview to another page.

I tried

```
<div phx-disconnected="disconnected">
```

in the html.heex file and

```
@impl true
def handle_event("disconnected", %{"data" => page_content}, socket) do
  IO.puts("I have been triggered")
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

in the live.ex file, but it is not working. I tried the suggestion in the [link](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/issues/123) Hedde van der Heide put up:

```
defmodule LiveMonitor do
  use GenServer

  def monitor(socket_id, game_pid) do
      pid = GenServer.whereis({:global, __MODULE__})
      GenServer.call(pid, {:monitor, {socket_id, game_pid}})
    end

    def demonitor() do
      pid = GenServer.whereis({:global, __MODULE__})
      GenServer.call(pid, :demonitor)
    end

    def start_link(init_arg) do
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg, name: {:global, __MODULE__})
    end

    def init(_) do
      {:ok, %{views: %{}}}
    end

    def handle_call({:monitor, {socket_id, game_pid}}, {view_pid, _ref}, %{views: views} = state) do
      mref = Process.monitor(view_pid)
      {:reply, :ok, %{state | views: Map.put(views, view_pid, {socket_id, game_pid, mref})}}
    end

    def handle_call(:demonitor, {view_pid, _ref}, state) do
      {{_socket_id, game_pid, mref}, new_views} = Map.pop(state.views, view_pid)
      :erlang.demonitor(mref)
      # more logic ...
      new_state = %{state | views: new_views}
      {:reply, :ok, new_state}
    end

    def handle_info({:DOWN, _ref, :process, view_pid, _reason}, state) do
      IO.puts(":DOWN #{inspect view_pid}")
      {{_socket_id, game_pid, mref}, new_views} = Map.pop(state.views, view_pid)
      # more logic ...
      new_state = %{state | views: new_views}
      {:noreply, new_state}
    end
end
```

but to no avail, as the :DOWN call is never issued when leaving the page either through a link or through a sidebar router call.
Does this actually mean that the LiveView does not automatically close when leaving the LiveView page ?

Comment: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/issues/123

Comment: Unfortunately, the link does not solve the problem as the leaving of the LiveView page does not entail a disconnection from it.